# String "Contains" char function

Tags: c, strings

I wrote this function which does the following from scratch w/o looking for ways that it is typically done:

1. Accepts a `char c` to search for.
2. Accepts a `char* str` to search within.
3. Accepts a buffer pointer, and stores all indices of `c` that are in `str` inside the provided buffer.
4. Returns the # of times that `c` was found in `str`.

Please critique and also - Are there better alternatives to export the indices other than using a buffer ptr?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int str_contains(const char c, const char* str, int* output_buffer){
    int i, str_len;
    str_len = strlen(str);
    int *holder = malloc(str_len*sizeof(int));
    int holder_iteration = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < str_len; i++){
        if(str[i] == c){
            holder[holder_iteration++] = i;
        }
    }
    memcpy(output_buffer,holder,holder_iteration*sizeof(int));
    free(holder); 
    return holder_iteration;
}

int main(){
    char* myString = "Welcome to the jungle, baby. Do you like to juggle or jump around?";
    int* output = malloc(500*sizeof(int));
    int number = str_contains('a',myString,output);

    printf("# of times: %d\nIndices: \n",number);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++){
        printf("%d\n",output[i]);
}

free(output);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- The final `memcpy` may overflow `output_buffer`. I recommend to change the signature to

  ```
  int str_contains(const char * str, char c, int *indices, size_t indices_size);
  ```

  The caller shall compare the return value with the size of buffer it passed and act accordingly.
- Dynamic memory is uncalled for. You may safely collect indices directly into the passed buffer.
- There is no need for `strlen`.
- When appropriate, use pointers.

All that said,

```
int str_contains(const char * str, char c, size_t * indices, size_t indices_size)
{
    size_t occurrences = 0;
    for (char * cursor = str; *cursor; cursor++) {
        if (*cursor == c) {
            if (occurrences < indices_size) {
                indices[occurrences] = cursor - str;
            }
            occurrences++;
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

Comment: I like everything except the fact that`indices[0]` is never filled in because you incremented `occurrences` beforehand.  Also, `indices_size` shouldn't be a pointer type (your explanation was right but your code was not).

Comment: @JS1 Thanks, fixed. Shouldn't post an untested code under the influence.